# How can I install specific version of ffmpeg in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ffmpeg

As mentioned above I am working on installing an older version of FFmpeg for testing. Specifically, I want to install version 3.0.10.

I have tried with below command

sudo apt-get install ffmpeg=3.0.10

but it always returns the below error

E: Version '3.0.10' for 'ffmpeg' was not found.